# I need to submit my form instantly without using submit button in struts2 with html 5

Tags: struts2

Since I have save button in the right menu. so when I pressed save in the right menu, it should save the values into the bean without submitting the form.

```
  <form action="personal-info.action" id = "userform" name="userform" method="post">
      <div class="clearfix">
        <h2>Basic Information</h2>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group clearfix col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
                <label>Title</label>            
                <div>
                <s:select list="titleList" listKey="displayKey" onChange="jsFunction()"  listValue="displayValue"  name="title"   id ="title" cssClass="selectpicker show-tick" required="true"  />
                <!-- <select class="selectpicker show-tick" data-width="auto" name="title" required>
                  <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
                  <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
                  <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
                </select> -->
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group clearfix col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
                <label>Gender</label>
</form>
```

Comment: The form is *submitted* in either way you make a request to the action, it's unclear what do you mean *without submitting the form*.

Comment: I will explain. I have a form, that form contains continue button. normally I will do the submit through continue button. when I press the 'continue' button, all the values are populated into the bean perfectly. but I have one side menu, in that menu I have one link called 'save'. If I press save link, the form should submit immediately. that right menu save will come from some other jsp(implemented tiles framework). when I am filling the form, if I press 'save' it should save immediately to the bean, then I will take the values from the bean and I will set into the session. This is my problem

Comment: Please let me know how to use AJAX for submit. My form name is userForm - that is in personal-info.jsp, but I have to submit the form from right.jsp  through 'save' onclick. Please let me know. thanks for your help.

Comment: Check out essentially any Ajax tutorial; the S2 back end doesn't care how the form is submitted. If you're submitting JSON you'll probably want to use the Struts2 JSON Plugin.

Comment: I am not using any JSON and all . Please let me know how to  trigger submit to save the form values from another jsp.

Comment: no comments from anyone. Please reply.